# Is Refresh Token relevant for OIDC IdentityServer Azure AD SSO Implementation?

Tags: azure-active-directory, identityserver4, openid-connect, access-token, refresh-token

I have an implementation of IdentityServer4 which connects with Azure AD for authentication (OIDC). In the callback method, using the IdentityServertools, I am generating the access_token and redirecting the user to SPA with the same. The SPA then stores the access_token into localstorage and uses it for authentication.

Normally, when my SPA app hits the token endpoint of the IdentityServer4, it gives access_token and refresh_token and then uses refresh_token to re-authenticate a returning user.

In this case of SSO with Azure AD, do I need to generate refresh_token manually? If yes, I can build on top of default implementation and that's not the problem ([However, the docs suggest against of changing the IRefreshTokenService implementation or building something from scratch](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/refresh_tokens.html))

My real question is, is there a need of refresh_token here? Because refresh_tokens are stored in DB and never get's deleted and after sometime, these refresh_tokens table will swell (right now it already has 80k rows). The user is expected to click on a small tile inside SAP's Successfactor - that will open the signin/consent screen of Azure or will directly take the user to the main page where zhe will just answer a question and done. So it's hardly 2-3 mins business. So I can continue to generate access_tokens from my IdentityServer4 for every click as I don't expect the user to stay authenticated in the browser if zhe has logged out from SAP's Successfactor (or any other app linked with Azure).

Please advise, if I should generate refresh_token? Is it a good architecture?

Comment: It's unclear for me to understand your structure, but I think I can share some experience of me. Access token is used to prove the request is allowed to access the resource(such as api from ms or your custom api) and refresh token is used to refresh access token to make sure the access token isn't expired. Access token will expire in an hour by default and refresh token has 90 days. So I usually store the refresh token in azure key vault so when I wanna to refresh access token, I obtain the refresh token. And each time a new acces token returned, a new refresh token returned, so replace it.

Comment: The expired time for refresh token is much longer than access token's expired time. So we can easily find it is designed for some special scenarios, because we can also generate a new access token in other way such as using msal or sign in again. As you said in the question, you can generate an access token by one click and you don't expect users to stay authenticated for a long time. So I think it's unnecessary for you to use refresh token.

Comment: Thank you so much Tiny for the answer. My product has 10 customers and for all of the, I persist the refresh_token and its hash in a table. However, for this client, they need SSO and they have implemented Free Pass AD. So that restricts my operation and hence I had to take this shortcut. I love your explanation. It's very clear. Thank you once again :)

Comment: Thanks for your response and your agreement. I'll post my comment as an answer, if you feel it a little helpful to you, could you pls pick it as the answer? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access token is used to prove the request is allowed to access the resource(such as api from ms or your custom api) and refresh token is used to refresh access token to make sure the access token isn't expired. Access token will expire in an hour by default and refresh token has 90 days.

At this point, we can easily find the refresh token is designed for some special scenarios because the expired time for refresh token is much longer than access token's expired time, but we can also generate a new access token in other way such as using msal or sign in again.

As you said in the question, you can generate an access token by one click and you don't expect users to stay authenticated for a long time. So I think it's unnecessary for you to use refresh token.